# non equi join returns non existing column names

Tags: r, data.table, non-equi-join

I am unable to do a basic non equi join in two data.tables in R without the error:
`argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[2]='abs(x.val - i.val)'`

A min. example to show the error.

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(1); dt1 <- data.table(id= sample(letters[1:3],size = 10,replace = T),val = rnorm(10,mean = 5,sd = 2))
set.seed(2); dt2 <- data.table(id= sample(letters[1:3],size = 10,replace = T),val = rnorm(10,mean = 5,sd = 2))
dt1[dt2,on = .(id,abs(x.val - i.val) <1),nomatch=0]
#> Error in colnamesInt(x, names(on), check_dups = FALSE): argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[2]='abs(x.val - i.val)'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

It must be something fundamental I am missing.

*Note: I have deliberately kept column names identical in both data tables to test the x. and i. functionality of data.table.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use a variable calculation in the `on=` argument. You can get *a* result if you break it out so you're just joining on `id` - `dt1[dt2,on = .(id), abs(x.val - i.val) <1, nomatch=0, allow.cartesian=TRUE]` - not sure what your intended output is however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two steps as `on` only accepts `=`,`<` or `>` :

```
dt1[dt2,on = .(id),nomatch=0,allow.cartesian=T][abs(val - i.val)<1]

   id      val    i.val
1:  a 3.142866 3.175512
2:  b 4.421077 3.494669
3:  b 4.401570 3.494669
4:  a 4.988466 4.428577
5:  a 3.142866 2.931430
6:  a 4.988466 4.943710
7:  a 4.988466 4.267357
8:  a 3.142866 2.769503
```

Or to avoid cartesian product:

```
dt2[,`:=`(val_min=val-1,val_max=val+1)]
dt1[dt2,.(id,x.val,i.val),on = .(id,val>val_min,val<val_max),nomatch=0]

   id    x.val    i.val
1:  a 3.142866 3.175512
2:  b 4.421077 3.494669
3:  b 4.401570 3.494669
4:  a 4.988466 4.428577
5:  a 3.142866 2.931430
6:  a 4.988466 4.943710
7:  a 4.988466 4.267357
8:  a 3.142866 2.769503
```

Comment: Your answer works for small data.tables, but when each data.table has tens of thousands of rows and the id column matches 100s of times, the resultant number of rows soon gets bloated up, before even reaching the filter step 2. Is there a way to limit the memory blast?

Comment: I would create `val_min:=val-1`,`val_max:=val+1` one one of the tables and then use `foverlaps` on interval `val_min`-`val_max` vs `val`-`val`

Comment: Instead of `foverlaps` what if I use your above suggestion in non.equi join itself? So we do `on = .(id,val_max > i.val, val_min<i.val)`. Why would this not work?

Comment: This works. Just add `id` in the J columns list, and we are ready to go.